# What is the time and space complexity of Rete algorithm

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, runtime-analysis, pattern-recognition, space-analysis

I am working on pattern matching algorithm. Its working and using very less memory. For the comparison, I have to compare it with the Rete Algorithm. I have checked it in the thesis of the author, some of his paper and he has provided some complexities which are not based on then, nor does its efficiency is provided in the space complexity.

My algorithm despite large inputs worst case is $O(n^2)$. Can someone point me to a good reference where I can find its complexity? I have been searching for a while now, and I did not even get the pseudo code. Things not to consider in order to save your time is algorithms, software, expert systems based on Rete algorithm e.g. Jess etc. 
reference link for algorithm thesis pdf  [Click to download](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/464e/b245ff9822defa8db82c385ff1fd0b0b6ffe.pdf)

citation of the paper "Forgy, C.L., 1982. Rete: A fast algorithm for the many pattern/many object pattern match problem. Artificial intelligence, 19(1), pp.17-37."

Comment: You need to give a proper reference for this "Rete" algorithm. Have you tried analysing it yourself? Have you compared the efficacy of both algorithms?

Comment: i want the original source, it is available in JESS as a code but i cannot use it being an external source

Comment: That's not an issue here because we don't like source code, anyway. (If it's a research paper, chances are there is no implementation at all, or the one they have was never published. It sucks, but still.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found what was needed, thought i wil share here for others who might need it.
http://reports-archive.adm.cs.cmu.edu/anon/1995/CMU-CS-95-113.pdf

Comment: And what's in there? Links break.

Comment: its working, link is fine